# Qt application on MacOS Mojave not respecting system language

Tags: c++, macos, qt, localization, macos-mojave

I have a Qt-based desktop application for Windows/Mac that's localized for English and German.  The app is written to use the system language to determine its startup language, using the Qt QLocale API:

```
QLocale sysLocale = QLocale::system();
QString translatorFileName = sysLocale.name(); // en_US, de_DE, etc
```

This was working as expected as of MacOS High Sierra(10.13.2).  On Mojave(10.14.1), this call is now always returning English for the language component regardless of the system language, i.e. if I change the system language and region to German/Germany, I expect `de_DE` to be returned as the locale name, but Qt returns `en_DE`.  I found that modifying the value of the `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` key in the application's `Info.plist` file will override the system locale in some situations but it also behaves differently between High Sierra and Mojave

I've [opened an issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-72491) on the Qt bug report forums as well that has more detail, trying to determine whether this issue stems from Qt or from an API change in Mojave.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem at macos.  I deleted the tip "development localization" which value is "english", and `QLocale::language()` return the right value.